# Call GetAsync from a WebAPI controller

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to return a HTTP result from a controller method in ASP.NET WebAPI. I am calling a `GetAsync` method, so I need to use async-await and return a `Task<T>`.

This is the controller method, of course, simplified for illustrative purposes:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> MyMethod()
{   
    var url = @"http://localhost/whatever";
    return await HttpGet<string>(url);  
}
```

And the HTTP call method, with parameters and Authorization abstracted away:

```
private async Task<T> HttpGet<T>(string url)
{
    var _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();

    throw new Exception($"{response.StatusCode} - {response.RequestMessage}");              
}
```

I get an error below after `return await` in `HttpGet` method:

> "**Message**": "An error has occurred.",
>
> "**ExceptionMessage**": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '', line 1, position 1.",
>
> "**ExceptionType**": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException"

Any advice?

Comment: This sort of error often appears if the json returned from your GetAsync is invalid.  Without seeing it, you may want to manually grab it and test it with something like https://jsonlint.com/ to ensure it's valid json.

Comment: It might not even be json.  Debug and check out the raw response itself before trying to parse it.

Comment: So you don't think the problem is with the return type being `Task<string>`, instead of just `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the return type of the HTTP call. It was a list of objects, while I was telling `ReadAsAsync<T>` to expect a `string`.

This solved it:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<MyClass>> MyMethod()
{   
    var url = @"http://localhost/whatever";
    return await HttpGet<List<MyClass>>(url);  
}
```